# order of evaluation issue react native vs browser

Tags: javascript, react-native, operator-precedence

I have an issue with, what I think it may be, an order of evaluation issue - but I can't figure it out exactly.
The code runs in a react-native environment, but the function is pure JS, so it can be run in browsers as well.

So, I have made a small function that creates a color representation in hsla() format. It does not return the string value directly, instead, it returns a function that uses the initial h,s,l,a values, and it accepts further overrides for l and a so I can tweak them in place. The function is below:

```
function Color(h, s, l, a) {
    return (L, A) => {
        let LL = (l || 0) + (L || 0);
        if (LL < 0) { LL = 0; }
        if (LL > 100) { LL = 100 }

        return `hsla(${h || 0},${s || 0}%,${LL}%,${A || a || 1.0})`;
    }
};
```

The problem is it behaves differently over the alpha value between the browser environment and the react-native environment. Specifically, when I try to do this:

```
var blue=Color(240,100,50);
var semiTransparentBlue = blue(0, 0.5); // 0 lightness adjustment, 0.5 alpha opacity
console.log("The hsla representation of the color is:",semiTransparentBlue);
```

in a browser environment, it correctly returns the string `"hsla(240,100%,50%,0.5)"`.

In react-native however:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import Color from "../libs/Color.js"; // the Color function is exported as-is in this file

export default class coloredComponent extends React.Component{
  render = ()=>{
    var blue=Color(240,100,50);
    var semiTransparentBlue = blue(0, 0.5); // 0 lightness adjustment, 0.5 alpha opacity
    // the above color function returns `"hsla(240,100%,50%,1)"`
    // instead of `"hsla(240,100%,50%,0.5)"`, wrong alpha value
    console.log("The hsla representation of the color is:",semiTransparentBlue);

    return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: semiTransparentBlue }} />
}
```

it returns `"hsla(240,100%,50%,1)"`.
Adding console.log()s in the returned function shows that I do not get undefined values for either the L or A params (in the returned color function). Actually, it does not return at all any different alpha value than 1, I tried with 0.0, 0.1, and others, it always returns 1 for the alpha.

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong ?

Comment: `it correctly returns the string "hsla(240,100,50,0.5)"` your code would return the string `"hsla(240,100%,50%,0.5)"`

Comment: With apologies, I don't believe that the three lines of code shown combined with the definition of `Color` shown produce different results in React Native than in a browser, that's got to be observational error. Something **else** is going on. So I would focus on finding out what that something else is.

Comment: the fact that the code WILL return two `%` and the reported output includes *none* suggests the actual code is different from the code in the question

Comment: Sorry for that, I mistyped the output in the comments. It does actually include the %. I will update the original post to fix that.